# Why does my program act different every time?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a console version of the game "I packed my suitcase...".
The basic idea is that i have a .txt file with about 4.3k random nouns in it, one word per line. I want to read out the words from this file and put them into a `vector<string>`. Next steps would be to have another vector with the words that the player has to keep in mind and so on.

But I struggle on a very early stage right now. 
What happens almost every time I run the code is that it just stops right after the line "Computer always starts. Have fun!" is printed to the console. However, I tried multiple `cout` statements in the end and I used to get some values. But they were always different. E.g ranging from 0 to 4308 (the exact number of lines) when printing vector.size(). In the last 30 minute the program never reached one of the couts.

- Using Clion 2016.1.1 with CMake 3.5.1 bundle under linux mint
- access to file.txt is not restricted in any way
- the path for file.txt is correct

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int player_score;
    string player_name;
    string line;
    vector <string> words_list;

    ifstream file;
    file.open("/home/rainbowterminal/ClionProjects/PackingBags/file.txt", ios_base::in);


    if(!file)
    {
        cerr << "Couldn't open file" << endl;
    }
    else

        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            words_list.push_back(line);
        }
    file.close();
    Player *player;
    player = new Player;

    cout << "Hey and welcome to 'I packed my suitcase and take with me'. You won't beat it. Promise." << endl;
    cout << "To start playing just enter your name" << endl;

    cin >> player_name;
    player->set_name(player_name);

    cout << "Okay " << player->get_name() << ", let's do this! You're a playing 'I packed my suitcase and take with me" << endl;
    cout << "against the computer. Just repeat the words printed to the console" << endl;
    cout << "and add an own word in the end. DO NOT seperate by commata. Letter case" << endl;
    cout << "doesn't matter. Computer always starts. Have fun! " << endl;



    //srand ((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    //int random = (int) (rand() % words_list.size());
    cout << words_list.size();
    cout << words_list[100];
    cout << player->get_name();
    //vector<string> used_words;
    //used_words.push_back(words_list[randomIndex]);



    return 0;
}
```

As suggested i broke it down to the basic problem. What happens with this piece of code is that

```
cout << words_list.size();
```

only returns the size of the vector in  only 50% of the trys.

```
int main() {
    string line;
    vector <string> words_list;

    ifstream file;
    file.open("/home/rainbowterminal/ClionProjects/PackingBags/file.txt", ios_base::in);

    if(!file) {
        cerr << "Couldn't open file" << endl;
    }
    else {

        while (getline(file, line)) {
            words_list.push_back(line);
        }
    }

    file.close();


    cout << words_list.size();


}
```

[file.txt](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03104211567220592833)

If anybody could me give me a hint what I did wrong I'd be more than happy  to work this out on my own.

Comment: Off topic performance note: `endl` is very expensive. It forces a flush to the underlying medium. You can replace most of them with the EOL character `'\n'`

Comment: You should probably add some `curly brackets` to your else case.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear. The program here does nothing apart from reading from a file and printing something. We don't have the file. There's nothing we can check. Try to produce a [mcve], otherwise I don't see how anyone can help. Anyway: this error that you are getting... Is it always the same, or does it change every time? If it changes you probably have some wrong memory access, like: reading an uninitialised variable (maybe a pointer?), reading an array out of bounds, things like those.

Comment: Also off topic: There doesn't seem to be any need for `player` to be dynamically allocated. `Player player;` should do everything you need it to do and gives you one less memory leak..

Comment: Try compiling with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong except: when player is created there is no check that it worked (you don't need to dynamically allocate it anyway) and player_score is uninitialized (but it isn't used anyway).  I don't see any other way something could be uninitialized but if player failed to be created that could be a problem because it is used afterwards and that is undefined behaviour so that could make random results.  The most likely thing is that getline fails for some reason and exits the loop prematurely - that isn't checked either.

Comment: This bit in player.h doesn't do anything: `int score = 0;bool fail = false;` you need to put the assignments in the constructor initializer list.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: In C++11 and beyond it is legal to initialize a member variable in the member declaration itself. It will be used when a constructor does not initialize that variable.

Comment: @rodrigo  That's cool!  Actually that is why I am a member of SO - you continueally learn some little thing.  Thanks very much.

Comment: `Player *player;   player = new Player;`  -- Are you a Java programmer by any chance?  All you need is this in C++:  `Player player;`  Also, what are you trying to do here?  `cout << words_list[100];`  ?  This is undefined behavior if there is no `words_list[100]` available.  Better yet:  `cout << words_list.at(100);` and see what happens.

Comment: You are not writing the `<< endl` after the `cout << word_list.size()`. So maybe your last three lines are all mixed in the same line, and then, depending on how Clion handles the non EOLed line, it is not even shown. Try adding a `<< endl` at the end of these last three lines.

Comment: @rodrigo Wow! This was it. I was totally not clear about this and didn't even see this when searching for errors. Thank you very much! Also thanks to anyone else here. For those who are wondering about the pointers and other potientally unnecessary stuff, this was just out of my own curiosity.